# Showing that $\mathcal{L}_{col}(A) \subset \mathcal{L}_{col}(B)$ if and only if $\mathcal{L}^{\perp}_{col}(B) \subset \mathcal{L}^{\perp}_{col}(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I saw a proof in a book that relied on the following statement for a key step. It didn't give a proof for it and so I was wondering if it was trivially obvious or very intuitive. It states that $\mathcal{L}_{col}(A) \subset \mathcal{L}_{col}(B)$ if and only if $\mathcal{L}^{\perp}_{col}(B) \subset \mathcal{L}^{\perp}_{col}(A)$.

Here, $\mathcal{L}_{col}(A)$ means the column space of a matrix $A$. More rigorously, if $A$ is a $p$ x $q$ matrix where $A = (a_1, \ldots, a_q)$ with vectors $a_i$, then $\mathcal{L}_{col}(A)$ is defined to be:

$$
\mathcal{L}_{col}(A) = \{w = \sum_{i=1}^{q}c_ia_i: c_i \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$

Also, $\mathcal{L}^{\perp}_{col}(A)$ means the orthogonal or null space of $A$. It is defined as:

$$
\mathcal{L}^{\perp}_{col}(A) = \{w : <w,v> = 0 \quad \forall \ v \in \mathcal{L}_{col}(A)\}
$$

Is there any easy way to see this or does it require a proof and/or is a standard result in matrix theory? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $ \mathcal{L}^{\perp}_{col}(A) $ as you have defined it is actually the null space of $A^{*} $ not $A$.

An easy way to see this is through the dimensions. Assuming both $A$ and $B$ are $p \times q$, they map vectors in $ \mathbb R^q \rightarrow \mathbb R^p$

$ p = dim(\mathcal{L}^{\perp}_{col}(A)) + dim(\mathcal{L}_{col}(A)) = dim(\mathcal{L}^{\perp}_{col}(B)) + dim(\mathcal{L}_{col}(B))$

If $\mathcal{L}_{col}(A) \subset \mathcal{L}_{col}(B) $

then

$ dim(\mathcal{L}_{col}(A)) \le dim(\mathcal{L}_{col}(B)) $.

This should lead you to the conclusion. For a more explicit proof, you can work by constructing bases for the 4 different subspaces.